# Файл JS пустой при его открытии, но не пустой на сайте

Tags: javascript, php

На каком-то сайте подключен JS по следующему типу

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/new_js.php"></script>
```

При открытии этого файла по ссылке видно, что он пустой, но он не пустой, если смотреть его через F12 браузера после загрузки страницы.

Подскажите, как это делается ? Спасибо

Comment: посмотри во вкладке network - что именно приходит и какой запрос отправляется

Comment: Например проверяется referer

Comment: спасибо. Реферер помог